# How to combine Strings and SVG within a Combobox?

Tags: svg, combobox, javafx-8

I have to know how to combine strings and SVGs within a combobox.
For example the SVG should be at the end of a string to show if the String has already been set somewhere.
So an item that already appears should be something like:
"This string already appears somewhere else" + mySVG.

If the string doesnt appear somewhere else the items value is simply the string itself.

Showing the string is no problem, my problem starts at adding the SVG.

My SVG is this:

```
SVGPath mySVG = new SVGPath();
mySVG.setContent("M0,4.2l1.4,-0.3L3,5.7A13,13 0 0,1 7.4,0H8.5A15,15 0 0,0 4,7.2L2.5,7.5Z");
```

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting a cell factory to the `ComboBox`:

```
public class JavaFxTest2 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("apple", "banana", "orange");
        comboBox.setCellFactory(l -> new ListCell<String>() {
            private SVGPath mySVG;

            {
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
                mySVG = new SVGPath();
                mySVG.setContent("M0,4.2l1.4,-0.3L3,5.7A13,13 0 0,1 7.4,0H8.5A15,15 0 0,0 4,7.2L2.5,7.5Z");
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    if ("banana".equals(item)) {
                        setGraphic(mySVG);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    setText(item);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                }
            }

        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(comboBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```